# Do i need special ball valve for hot water heating system? Is WOG rating ok?

Tags: plumbing, water-circulating-heating

I am installing zone valves but want to isolate each loop with ball valves. can I use regular plumbing ball valves for this. Max temp would be 180 F.

Comment: Look at product specs. Most are rated at 200F or higher. Many are 400.

Comment: Commonly metal + teflon (PTFE) so temperature limits are quite high, indeed.

Answer (score 1):

### You're fine

Ordinary WOG (water, oil, gas) rated, metal-bodied ball valves are going to be rated for hydronic temperatures and beyond; if you want to make extra sure, you can check the specifications of the valve you're looking at for a WSP (Working Steam Pressure) rating, which a typical ball valve (using the Watts LFFBV as an example) [will have as well](https://www.watts.com/products/Plumbing-Flow-Control-Solutions/Shutoff-Valves/Ball-Valves/LFFBV).  (Obviously, a plastic-bodied valve is going to have a much lower working temperature rating, and no WSP rating for that matter.)

Comment: So then is the only reason the handles may be blue or red is to help you identify a hot or cold valve when it's installed?

Comment: @SteveSh -- for bog-standard metal-body valves, yeah (many are other colors, I know most of the ones in my house have yellow handles for instance)